# KeyError when assigning ''praw.Reddit'' to variable

Tags: python, praw, reddit

I could successfully connect to reddit's servers with oauth2 some time ago, but when running my script just now, I get a `KeyError` followed by a `NoSectionError`. Code is below followed by exceptions, (The code has been reduced to its essentials).

```
import praw


# Configuration
APP_UA = 'useragent'
...
...
...

r = praw.Reddit(APP_UA)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Directory\Python\lib\configparser.py", line 843, in items
    d.update(self._sections[section])
KeyError: 'useragent'

A NoSectionError occurred when handling the above exception.
"During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:"

'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Directory\Python\Projects\myprj for Reddit, globaloffensive\oddshotcrawler.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = praw.Reddit(APP_UA)
  File "D:\Directory\Python\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 84, in __init__
    **config_settings)
  File "D:\Directory\Python\lib\site-packages\praw\config.py", line 47, in __init__
    raw = dict(Config.CONFIG.items(site_name), **settings)
  File "D:\Directory\Python\lib\configparser.py", line 846, in items
    raise NoSectionError(section)
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'useragent'
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try giving it a user_agent kwarg.

```
r = praw.Reddit(useragent=APP_UA)
```

Comment: Worked, but gave a new traceback error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Directory\Python\Projects\Oddshotcrawler for Reddit, globaloffensive\oddshotcrawler.py", line 19, in <module>
    r = praw.Reddit(useragent=APP_UA)
  File "D:\Directory\Python\lib\site-packages\praw\reddit.py", line 92, in __init__
    raise ClientException(message.format(attribute))
praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing. 
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the 'Reddit' class constructor, or as an environment variable.`

Comment: looks like your bot needs to be authorized, you can read about it here http://praw.readthedocs.org/en/stable/pages/oauth.html

Comment: what is APP_UA? I have been trying to find a complete working praw example but couldn't. I am not sure what to pass to praw.Reddit

Comment: @MonaJalal `APP_UA` is intended to represent the application user-agent string it's a variable that you define `APP_UA = 'mysite.com/wiki_bot_or_something'`. The variable should provide a description of what the bot/script does.

Comment: `r = praw.Reddit(APP_UA = 'mysite.com/wiki_bot_or_something')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 101, in __init__
    raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute))
praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing. 
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.` @John